# Call the SiriKit API to create Automation Shortcuts

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am using [react-native-siri-shortcut](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-siri-shortcut) and have successfully created a "Shortcut", however, it seems that it's only a shortcut that takes the user back to my App.

I've started using Swift 5 and XCode 13.2, so happy to receive answers using these languages too.

What I'm trying to do is allow them to create Automation shortcuts from within the app, whether it be "Open this app at 5pm every day" or something similar.

Is it possible to call the API to create Shortcut Automations? Is there another way, that doesn't use react-native-siri-shortcut?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Check out these two articles!
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app , https://medium.com/globant/integrating-siri-shortcuts-using-custom-intent-and-interface-in-ios-14-d3a84a933103

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure if your idea is suitable for the shortcut api as it is an automation.
Tasks like "Open this app at 5pm every day" via shortcuts, will lead you into permission issues. Even when guaranteeing full access - which could lead to security issues - your app won't open if the device is not unlocked. There would also be the question why would you want to open your app at 5pm every day? Without knowing the reason I would say "Shortcuts" feels not like the right solution for this.

Comment: If you could let me know what you want to achieve with the shortcut we can check if there is an other way for this.

Comment: I want to achieve the locating of a way to create any automation my phone, using Siri and Shortcuts/Automation

Comment: I’m not sure if this is possible at all. Apple provides an own app (Shortcuts) for this.
If you want your users to create any shortcut then implement a "deep linking" function that opens the shortcut app and lets the users create their shortcut or automation.If your users should be able to create shortcuts that are specific to your app, then you can provide “Offering Actions in the Shortcuts App” see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/offering_actions_in_the_shortcuts_app

Comment: If your want users to automate your app specific things (linke send a message every day etc.) you could provide a shortcut for this or you could us the background task option. 
BTW: If you only want to “copy” the function of the Shortcut app I doubt that you will pass the AppStore review.

Comment: Please let me know if I misunderstood something.
It might help as well if you could explain a bit what your app should do in general and where / how you want to use the shortcut features.

Comment: PS: have you already checked  https://github.com/a2/swift-shortcuts ?

Comment: @DoTryCatch Thanks so much for the suggestions, unfortunately, I did ask Apple with my dev tokens and they said it wasn't possible. Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: No problem! Should I summarise it in an answer?

Comment: Feel free, you've earned it, and it will help who ever searches for it next :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interacting with apples Shortcut app:

- use deep linking to allow users to open the shortcuts app, open a single shortcut or run a specific shortcut.
- provide a shortcut for your app that then can be used within the ShortCut app like: MyApp - show me the latest news from "selected blog"

Things worth mentioning when working with shortcut automations:

- automations require special permissions to run without user interaction
- many automations won't run if the device is locked

In app automations (IOS):
You can use `Background Tasks`, `BGTaskScheduler`, `UserNotifications (APNS)` etc. to automate things from within your app.

In app automations (MacOS):

On macOS you can easily automate things using `crontab` - when the user is logged in - or `launchctl` if you want to be more fexible (attention for daemons are root permissions required!)

> **Notice:**
> Any kind of automation can cause security issues if it can run without user interactions, especially if it has root privileges.

Links according to this topic/answer:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/offering_actions_in_the_shortcuts_app
- https://medium.com/infonity-tech/shortcut-deeplinking-for-ios-developer-64f75171c7de
- https://medium.com/globant/integrating-siri-shortcuts-using-custom-intent-and-interface-in-ios-14-d3a84a933103
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/6462-siri-shortcuts-tutorial-in-ios-12
- https://github.com/a2/swift-shortcuts

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive research and help on this topic!

I understand this problem more now, and will try to implement your methods in my solutions!

Cheers, 

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Siri shortcut api is provided to developers so that they could provide their apps main functionality to the system (siri , shortcut).

if you want to create an automation app i have some other suggestions for automating different tasks:

Automation tasks that needs permission:

these are tasks that iOS won’t delegate to your app like opening an app on schedule.
a way to go around this is using your apps deep link or other apps that provide a deep link and set a local notification or push notification with that link. when you click on the notification your app opens up if the link is yours you are done if not you call the deep link and other apps will open. problem with this approach is callbacks and getting notified when the job is done and you have to fire the next task.

these are some ios system URL schemes and they are available for other apps as well. They usually mention the schemes in their websites.

https://github.com/phynet/iOS-URL-Schemes

Location based automation services:

you could use geofencing capability and mix it with push notification or local notification and continue the rest of the tasks in your app when your user is in his marked location. take a look at

https://www.raywenderlich.com/17649843-geofencing-with-core-location-getting-started

Timebase automation services:

time-based automations could be achieved by background tasks and if you could provide server-side they could also be achieved by push notifications.

Complex multistep automation services:

for this purpose, you could use some open-source automation available and implement their APIs in your app like n8n

https://n8n.io

and on each step of the workflow notify your app so as the main interface of the automation it could show the current step.

these are just some suggestions based on possible workarounds.